# Make a horizontal line from the current indented location to the right margin

Tags: spacing, rules

I want to be able to do something like:

```
\hspace{2cm} \hrule
```

and have LaTeX give me a line that goes from 2cm past the left margin, to the right margin. I've looked around and as a LaTeX newbie it seems to be a non-trivial thing to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `\hrulefill` for the purpose. Please see the three examples
contained in the following file.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

Fill the whole horizontal width

\hrulefill

\bigskip 

Fill the whole horizontal width after a cetain space 

\hspace{2cm}\hrulefill

\bigskip 

Fill between two texts

Make a horizontal \hrulefill line from the current indented

\end{document}
```

The following is the output.

[image]

In order to know more about `\hrulefill`, please [see here](http://insti.physics.sunysb.edu/latex-help/ltx-150.html).

Comment: All your lines start with the indentation box of width `\parindent`.

Comment: @jfbu If any user does not want that, the solution is very simple, either put a `\noindent` before each one, or use a global `\parindent=0.0mm` in the preamble.

Comment: I'm going with this answer because it's the simplest one. I didn't realise there was a simple command \hrulefill. Thanks!

Comment: @nebffa Thanks, glad to be of assistance. See the above comment from jfbu, and my comment as answer.

Answer (score 2):

Define a command for this; `\MyRule` has an optional argument allowing you to specify the distance from the left margin (default=`0pt`, meaning that using just `\MyRule` will gove you a rule spanning the whole text width):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}%just for the example

\newcommand\MyRule[1][0pt]{\par\noindent\hspace*{#1}\hrulefill\par}

\begin{document}

text
\MyRule[0cm]
\MyRule[2cm]
\MyRule[4in]
\MyRule[0.5\textwidth]

\end{document}
```

[image]

The `showframe` package was only used to have a visual guideline showing the margins.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to emulate the behavior of `\hrule` (which is a primitive command, to be used with care), you can benefit from another primitive, `\moveright`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newcommand{\movedrule}[1]{%
  \par
  \nointerlineskip
  \moveright#1\vbox{
    \hrule width\dimexpr\linewidth-#1\relax
  }
  \nointerlineskip
}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[2]
\hrule
\lipsum[2]
\movedrule{2cm}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]